# Logic from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I move this view to the controller?

Model

```
class Reserve < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

View

```
<% @user_list.each do |user| %>

<td><%= user.name %></td>

<% Reserve.where(:user_id=>user.id).each do |a| %>
  <td><%= a.date %></td>
  <td><%= a.time %></td>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
 @user_list = User.all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you could replace the query, access the user.reserves and iterate over them:

```
<% @user_list.each do |user| %>
  <td><%= user.name %>:</td>
  <% user.reserves.each do |reserve| %>
    - <td><%= reserve.date %></td><br>
    - <td><%= reserve.time %></td><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, use `includes` to get the User reserves, instead querying one by one per each user:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_list = User.includes :reserves
  end
end
```

I don't know your case, but to work with `reserves` I had to create an entry in the inflections config file:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'reserve', 'reserves'
end
```

Comment: question is reserves = Reserve.where(:user_id=>user.id) am I right?

Comment: `User.includes :reserves` does what you want to do instead hitting again the db with a where clause for each user, give it a try. And yes, it is @John

Comment: last question what if I wanted to iterate within the controller and created an object reserve = 'Reserve.where(:user_id=>user.id)' and placed reserve.each do |f| in the view is it possible to pass the user.id in the controller and how? Thank you

Comment: It depends why do you want to do that, you can get the reserves from each user by using includes. If in the other hand, if you want to do that, then you need to send from the view to the controller the `user.id`, this can be done defining a new route or by using AJAX.